# Elasticsearch max field value with respect to another field

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I perform a elasticsearch query if I have a field called

"bytes_received" and another called "ip_addr"

and I would like to query the ip_addr that has the most bytes_received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done with ES's multi-bucket based aggregation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-sort.html).

```
{
    "sort" : { "bytes_received" : {"order" : "desc"}}
}
```